# Proving the identity between Beta and Gamma functions using semi-group property of the Gamma.

Tags: probability, gamma-function, beta-function

Reading the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25973/32735), it seems like the relation:

$$B(t,s)=\frac{\Gamma(t)\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(t+s)} \tag{1}$$

follows from the semi-group property of the Gamma distribution since "the integral of a convolution of two functions is the product of their integrals".

The semi-group property being spoke of here:

$$\gamma_t*\gamma_s=\gamma_{t+s} \tag{2}$$

where:

$$\gamma_t(x):=\frac{x_+^{t-1}e^{-x}}{\Gamma(t)}$$

Seems to indicate there is some elegant proof for equation (1) using equation (2). Is this true or am I imagining things? And if there is, can someone show me what it might be?

Comment: This is outlined at the bottom of [this Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the last part there: $\int (f*g)(x) dx = B(x,y) \Gamma(x+y)$? Why?

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function):

With $f(u) = e^{-u} u^{x-1} 1_{u > 0}$ and $g(u) = e^{-u} u^{y-1} 1_{u > 0}$, we have
$$\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \, du \cdot \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(u) \, du
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (f * g)(u) \, du
= B(x,y) \Gamma(x+y).$$

To show the last equality, note that
$$(f*g)(u)
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) g(u-t) \, dt
= \int_0^u e^{-u} t^{x-1} (u-t)^{y-1}  \, dt
= e^{-u} u^{x+y-1} \int_0^1 s^{x-1} (1-s)^{y-1} \, ds$$
where the last step comes from the substitution $t=us$.

Comment: Thank you. But we just went ahead and worked out the algebra here. I don't think we managed to take a short-cut via the fact that $\gamma_t * \gamma_s=\gamma_{t+s}$. Or did I miss something?